# Interpolating xyz-points to raster in QGIS

Tags: qgis, interpolation

I want to interpolate xyz-point data to a raster.

```
x,y,z  
3435339.20,5412714.28,-0.22  
3435340.19,5412714.28,0.06  
3435339.20,5412715.28,-0.20
```

I imported it as csv and saved it as shape. Then I tried the build-in TIN and IDW interpolation with z as attribute. Because I have close to 9 million points I set the output pixelsize to 10 for the trial. This should be easy and quick. I have done it before with other point data. My problem is that the TIN interpolation just causes QGIS to crash and IDW Interpolation stops at 100%, freezes and just creates a unreadable output file.

Here are the parameters for the IDW-Interpolation:

```
Algorithm 'IDW interpolation' starting…
Input parameters:
{ 'DISTANCE_COEFFICIENT' : 2, 'EXTENT' : '3434785.27,3439126.71,5412714.28,5420285.89 [EPSG:4326]', 'INTERPOLATION_DATA' : 'C:/.../points.shp::~::0::~::2::~::0', 'OUTPUT' : 'C:/.../raster.tif', 'PIXEL_SIZE' : 10 }
```

This is what I tried for the TIN-Interpolation

```
Algorithm 'TIN interpolation' starting…
Input parameters:
{ 'EXTENT' : '3434785.27,3439126.71,5412714.28,5420285.89 [EPSG:4326]', 'INTERPOLATION_DATA' : 'C:/.../points.shp::~::0::~::2::~::0', 'METHOD' : 0, 'OUTPUT' : 'C:/.../raster.tif', 'PIXEL_SIZE' : 10 }
```

With gdal rasterize (I am not sure whether the points a regular) I am able to create a raster but it just has 1 value.

```
gdal_rasterize -l hj -a z -ts 1.0 1.0 -a_nodata 0.0 -te 3434785.27 5412714.28 3439126.71 5420285.89 -ot Float32 -of GTiff C:/.../points.shp C:/..../raster_3.tif
```

I am trying to create a raster out of this data since two days. I am using QGIS version 3.10.2-A Coruña.

Comment: Please edit your question so it contains all parameters of the algorithms.